# How to remove the word ‘api’ from Azure functions url

Tags: azure, azure-functions

When you create an Http triggered API, Azure function hosts it on

```
https://[function-app-name].azurewebsites.net/api/[Route-configured-in-application]
```

Is there any way of getting rid of the term api from the URL and make it look like:

```
https://[function-app-name].azurewebsites.net/[Route-configured-in-application]
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Edit the host.json file and set routePrefix to empty string:

```
{
  "http": {
    "routePrefix": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Can you please mark this as answer? Thank you!

Comment: It took a few minutes to update for me but this did indeed work.

Comment: Here is the host.json reference to read while you wait https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#http

Comment: Answer is now outdated.

Comment: For functions v2 see the Answer from Denis to get this working as this answer will not work

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski -Stating the answer is outdated without providing a solution is also outdated.

Answer (score 38):

The Azure Functions v2 solution is covered in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52128045/704738), the http bit needs to be wrapped in an extensions property.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "routePrefix": "customPrefix"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, it's working for me. thank you very much!
@Mayank please mark this as the answer, your answer is not working :(

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer no longer works if you're using version 2 functions, instead you need to put the http settings in an extensions property:

```
"extensions": {
    "http": {
        "routePrefix": ""
    }
}
```

You can get caught out looking at the [hosts.json reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json) because if you only look at the [http section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#http) it shows just the http properties so make sure to check the start of the doc for the top level hosts.json format.

Answer (score 7):

You could also leverage the power of Azure Function Proxies for this, which might be better if you want to be explicit about which methods or routes you want to access.

Just create a `proxy.json` file and add the following piece of JSON to it.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
  "proxies": {
    "myazurefunctionproxy": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "methods": ["GET"],
        "route": "/{slug}"
      },
      "backendUri": "https://%WEBSITE_HOSTNAME%/api/{slug}"
    },
  }
}
```

This sample will redirect all GET-requests to a route with `/api/` prefixed.