# How to change the base "/api" path on Azure Functions (v2)?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

In azure functions we create the function route / name, but it Always preceded by  /api

on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-serverless-api) we read:

> Note that you did not include the /api base path prefix in the route template, as this is handled by a global setting.

But, 
**How to change this base "/api" path ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the **routePrefix** specified in the **host.json**:

```
{
  "http": {
    "routePrefix": "whatever"
  }
}
```

You can set this for example using kudu:

```
https://<YOURSITE>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole/?shell=powershell
```

Navigate to `site -> wwwroot` and edit the host.json

---

**Note:** This **does not work for v2**. Please use the [answer from truongx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52128045/1163423) instead.

Comment: Does not work any more, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52128045/275501 below from https://stackoverflow.com/users/2171887/truongx instead

Comment: @goofballLogic You are right, I edited my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 31):

Accepted answer does not work for **v2** anymore (source: [Azure-Functions-Host Gitub repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/host.json-(v2))). For v2 you need to wrap `http` settings inside `extensions` object. Working **host.json** example:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "routePrefix": "customPrefix"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that the Azure Portal "test" functionality still seems to read the routePrefix from the original spot, so I ended up having to put it in both places...

Comment: hi @goofballLogic, your comment saved my day! I kept testing it using portal test feature which throws error 404! How did you update it for Test? i coudn't find the place where i can update.

Comment: @PreetiJoshi I just manually updated host.json file to have "http" both inside "extensions" and also at the top level