# Azure Function (using DI) cannot remove "/api" route prefix

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions

So I'm aware of these two questions that seem to be asking the same thing:

[How to remove the word ‘api’ from Azure functions url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47312531/how-to-remove-the-word-api-from-azure-functions-url)

[How to change the base "/api" path on Azure Functions (v2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49362853/how-to-change-the-base-api-path-on-azure-functions-v2)

However, I can still not get rid of the "api" prefix in my route.

My `host.json` looks like:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "routePrefix": ""
    }
  }
}
```

And on my HttpTrigger I'm setting my custom route:

```cs
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "myapp")] HttpRequest request,
```

However, when I run the app locally the end point is coming up as:

```
[POST] http://localhost:7071/api/myapp
```

If I change my `host.json` to:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "routePrefix": "something"
    }
  }
}
```

My app is now running on:

```
[POST] http://localhost:7071/something/myapp
```

So it appears that giving an empty string `""` is just not working. Any ideas? (I've done all the usual stuff: clean solution, delete bin/obj folder etc.)

FYI from my function app I'm using:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.7" />
```

**EDIT:**

I'm also referencing these packages from the function app (though I don't see how this would cause this problem):

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault" Version="3.1.1" />
```

**EDIT 2**

I've narrowed down the problem to this code that is called in `Startup.cs`:

```cs
IConfiguration configuration = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IConfiguration>();

IConfiguration combinedConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddConfiguration(configuration)
    .AddAzureKeyVault(kvEndpoint, kvClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
    .Build();

builder.Services.AddSingleton(combinedConfig);
// <-- this line causes the prefix "" to revert to "/api"
```

It essentially is adding key vault as a configuration provider to the stack of providers all ready there. (Note it doesnt matter what .Add methods I call on configuration builder, its the registration that is causing a problem). Is there another way to write this maybe?

Comment: do you have something like Startup class in your azure function?

Comment: @IvanYang yes. I am using: `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions` package as well. Can this possibly be related?? :-)

Comment: hi, can you please show us all the packages and a sample code? and are you using some DI by adding the `Startup.cs` in your project? This should work and we used it many times.

Comment: Unfortunately that would be a lot of code and it might be too sensitive to post here. Yes I am using `Startup - Configure` to register dependencies and configuration and nothing else.  Though I'm not sure how registering dependencies would stop me from using `""` for my route prefix when simply specifying `"something"` as the route prefix works. Any ideas?

Comment: The dependencies I'm registering are agnostic to being used by a function app (i.e. they have nothing to do with function apps)

Comment: Same code remove the `/api` on my side. I am not sure what happened, but maybe you can use `Proxies.json` to acheive 'remove' the `/api`?

Comment: @bytedev, if possible, could you please just show the code in Startup.cs? by the way, your new edit in your post seems wrong:).

Comment: Why downvote this question?

Comment: @bytedev If `extensions.http.routePrefix = ""` is still not work, will you accecpt use proxy to 'remove' the `/api`?

Comment: @IvanYang damn your fast lol - hit refresh. I've narrowed down the problem.

Comment: @bytedev Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @BowmanZhu nope, I can see the line causing problem however I dont currently know another way to write the code I put in EDIT 2.  In fact I'm not sure if there is another way. I'm still confused why it would mess up only for empty string prefixes though. Very weird!

Comment: @bytedev, try to add this line of code in the Startup.cs: `builder.Services.Configure<HttpOptions>(options => options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty);`.

Comment: @IvanYang that does work. However, we are just overwriting whats in the host.json with that - thats later gonna confuse the hell out of someone :-). I'm going to research if there is a better way to add another config provider :-)

Comment: @bytedev, another possible solution, you can use IOptions, see this [doc](https://medium.com/@aranmulholland/injecting-application-settings-into-azure-functions-using-ioptions-f9ca07ac80ce).

Comment: @IvanYang thanks for your help. My answer/findings below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the mistake I seem to have made was very small. In the following code:

```cs
IConfiguration configuration = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IConfiguration>();

IConfiguration combinedConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddConfiguration(configuration)
    .AddAzureKeyVault(kvEndpoint, kvClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
    .Build();

builder.Services.AddSingleton(combinedConfig);
```

`ConfigurationBuild.Build()` actually returns a `IConfigurationRoot`, NOT a `IConfiguration` (`IConfigurationRoot` is a superset of `IConfiguration`). So when registering it I was loosing something (probably config provider information).

Simply changing:

```
IConfiguration combinedConfig
```

to

```
IConfigurationRoot combinedConfig
```

fixes the problem (or you can use `var`, which I probably should have!).

Though this fixes the problem I am still a little confused why before changing the `routePrefix` in `host.json` to some non-empty string works but setting it to empty string does not.  Would have thought simply having the setting in the `host.json` at all would just apply the value and not having it there would mean reverting to the default `"api"`.

Comment: Congratulations to solve this problem. You can mark your answer later, this will help others who meet the similar question.:)

Answer (score -1):

I tried, and it's working!

I used VS2019, Created Azure function default project with HTTP trigger and remove route prefix from `host.json`

[image]

**Proj file**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.31" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

After updating nuget packages with latest version, it's working.

[image]

**Proj file**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core" Version="3.0.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```